# Does water hardness affect the life of copper pipes?

Tags: leak, pipe

We have just completed the renovation works of our old home in Toronto. A short while later the pipes in bathrooms began to leak. The plumber may have used lower quality materials or lower class copper pipes for the work. Does  the hardness or softness of water actually  matter in the life of pipes?

Comment: Is it due to freezing weather?  What kind of leaking? (squirting, heavy drip, ... one drip per day)  Are the leaks at pipe joints, elbows, or random places?  Was the building heat off long enough for the interior to go below freezing?

Comment: I have never seen pipes begin to leak that quickly that were correctly installed. can you access above the area that is leaking and see if it is just a really slow drip that finally made it through, or if winter weather froze and cracked them?

Comment: Product or service recommendations, and contractor disputes, are both off topic here. I've edited the question down to the remaining on topic portion.

Comment: sounds like you used a lower class plumber that probably screwed up regular quality materials with a melonheaded approach and attention to detail. no skills means loads of thrills.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a well? In remodeling a home a few years ago, the home being on a well with very hard water, we were replacing a kitchen sink and before we were done we had replaced over 50' of copper piping that was as thin as tin foil. The house was on a well and I wish we would have gotten some tests done for acidity. Mike

Answer (score 1):

I'll bite. So sad. I agree **entirely** with Personal Privacy Advocate. If, he **actually** used copper plumbing & there hasn't been any freezing issue, then there's absolutely no reason for anything to leak **in the slightest**. Get a new plumber & don't accept anything but copper, nothing else yet outperforms nor outlasts it.

No level of water hardness would instantly wear out copper, not even a cement slurry. Was this the experience you had before the renovation & were replacing pipes every quarter, **no**. You only just now replaced decades-old copper **only** because of redesign, we might as well & the renovation's therefore a fully sound investment.

Report the guy to the Building Dept., they'll bring him back to do it right & actually inspect his work & his testing. Put a claim in on his insurance (if any existed before the leaks you've got a good shot) or send him the paid bill from the new plumber (repeatedly) & bad mouth the guy all over the internet.